# Nano able to read on write-only access file

Tags: permissions, rhel, setuid

User has write-only permissions on a file, unable to `cat` or `vi` but is able to `nano` normally. How is this possible?

I was wondering what happens if you only have write-access on a file and this was how I tested it.

```
# cd /home/tester
# cat hello.txt
Hello World!
# ls -l hello.txt
-rw------- 1 root root 13 Nov 17 01:55 hello.txt
# chmod o+w hello.txt
# ls -l hello.txt
-rw-----w- 1 root root 13 Nov 17 01:55 hello.txt
# su tester
$ cd ~
$ cat hello.txt
cat: hello.txt: Permission denied
$ nano hello.txt
```

For some reason, `nano` is able to read the file (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iGWG.png)). I've confirmed `vi` is not. My original hypothesis is that having write only permission allows you to only append the file like `echo "Hello" > hello.txt`.

(See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33bBw.png) for the actual commands I ran.)

#### Update

`ls -l "$(type -p nano)"` shows permissions `-rwsr-xr-x root root`.

Comment: `#` suggests you are still root. Are you sure you're tester? Can you do `whoami` right before you use nano?

Comment: @Tomasz I've done whoami and checked that I'm tester. I didn't know realise that # actually meant something. Thought it just meant commands. Its $ from su onwards

Comment: Make sure nano was not open before you changed the permissions (are you using it in the same terminal?) and check if your nano is not unexpectedly suid set: `ls -l "$(type -p nano)"`.

Comment: ```-rwsr-xr-x root root``` is the output when I ran this command as trader03/tester. So I assume thats what u meant by suid set, which is the "s" in user?

Comment: Yes. It is suid. This means whoever runs nano, the process has root privileges. This is not expected and shouldn't be happening in any normal environment. Find out with your administrator what the point is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-rwsr-xr-x root root` in the result of `ls -l "$(type -p nano)"` means it is setuid. As a result, whoever runs nano has root privileges. This is not expected and shouldn't be happening in any normal environment. Find out with your administrator what the point is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just one more question. If I were to attempt to remediate this, would it be just ```chmod u+x /usr/bin/nano``` ?

Comment: @ministic2001 `chmod u-s` should do. They're two unrelated things formally, so `+s` doesn't  cause `+x`.

Comment: Good catch @Tomasz. I think that’s actually a bad security hole, as anyone who can execute `nano` can view and (worse) edit any given file on the server. Probably even shell out as root. Tread carefully and *absolutely* inform the sysadmin.

Comment: The user may want to check if there are other executables in the same directory that shouldn't be setuid (some possibly _should_ be). It might have been a lazy operator who just changed all of them "for convenience".